# how can I specify lein library dependencies depending on the jvm version number

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm working on a clojure library with a native lib dependency.

I don't want upgrade to jre 7 and lose support for jre 6.

I'm hoping that for users with jre 6 to include a different dependency version to users using jre 7. What is the best way to do that?

The issue can be seen here.

https://github.com/zcaudate/sigmund/issues/2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Leiningen profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) or classifiers for what you are talking about.

### Profiles

```
(defproject im.chit/sigmund "0.2.0"
  :description "System analytics for Clojure"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[midje "1.5.0"]]}
             :jre6 {:jar-name "sigmund-jre6.jar"
                    :dependencies [[sigar/sigar "1.7.0-v20131027"]
                                   [sigar/sigar-native-deps "1.7.0-v20131027"]]}
             :jre7 {:jar-name "sigmund-jre7.jar"
                    :dependencies [[sigar/sigar "1.7.0-v20131027"]
                                   [sigar/sigar-native-deps "1.7.0-v20131027"]]}})
```

**Node:** The `jre6` and `jre7` profile names are arbitrary, and do *not* do anything beyond a standard lein profile. I just used meaningful names so their use would be obvious.

And, you can run tasks with both the `jre6` and `dev` profiles combined by separating them with a comma, on the command line.

```
$ lein with-profiles jre6,dev test
```

If you want to jar them with a single command, you would separate them with a colon.

```
$ lein with-profiles jre6:jre7 jar
```

### Classifiers

```
(defproject im.chit/sigmund "0.2.0"
  :description "System analytics for Clojure"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [sigar/sigar "1.7.0-v20131027"]
                 [sigar/sigar-native-deps "1.7.0-v20131027"]]
  :classifiers [["jre6" :jre6]]
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[midje "1.5.0"]]}
             :jre6 {}})
```

In this case, the default profile would correspond to the current version, supporting JRE 7, and the `:jre6` profile would be for the previous version.

```
$ lein jar
Created /Users/user1/sigmund/target/sigmund-0.2.0.jar
Created /Users/user1/sigmund/target/jre6/sigmund-0.2.0-jre6.jar
```

You would reference the "jre6" jar with the `:classifier` keyword in your `:dependencies` vector.

```
(defproject tester1 "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [sigmund "0.2.0" :classifier "jre6"]])
```

This method is limited because, due to the way the pom file is generated, you cannot specify different dependencies for each classified jar. Other settings affecting jaring, such as source directories and AOT, should work.